# Kid gets reincarnated into magic world finds a black wolf that could destroy country

Tags: story-identification, magic, magical-creatures, reincarnation

- in this world humans can’t use magic on their own so they contract magic beasts
- the mc is a prince and ends up sneaking out to contract a familiar but he ends up with a country destroying wolf because he just thought about the fluffiness after he saw him
- the mc also ends up being the master of a dryad after he saved its life

Comment: What work was this? Book, cartoon, anime, etc.?

Comment: Hi. How does reincarnation fit into this?

Comment: Anyway, sometimes we all need to just think about the fluffiness.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

This is *[Tensei Ouji wa Daraketai](https://myanimelist.net/manga/112534/Tensei_Ouji_wa_Daraketai)* (common English title of "The Reincarnated Prince Wants to Slack Off").

[image: Front cover of *Tensei Ouji wa Daraketai*]

> Haruto is an ordinary Japanese student who is tired of constant work and study. After getting hit by truck, he is reincarnated as Phil Graceheart, the youngest child in a royal family. When Phil is three years old, he gets a head injury that causes him to remember his former life.
>
> Armed with the knowledge of his past self, he is now on a mission to live a completely relaxing and carefree life.

Meeting the wolf:
[image: Meeting Diabolos]

Example of summoning contract:
[image: Haruto finds an example of the contract in his textbook]

Found with a search for "black wolf" on [r/Isekai](https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/), which brought me to [this topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/fnnq7w/recommend_some_isekai_mangaanime_please/), which mentioned *Tensei Ouji wa Daraketai* with the following description:

> The Reincarnated Prince Wants to Slack Off - This is every isekai ever, but i have a weakness towards it. It's about a guy who got isekaied and lives as a prince that has the power to adopt tons of pets. There is a sassy huge black wolf, a cat that can do a sonic spindash, a kangaroo that has a dimension pocket and so on... I love pets so i can't resist this one, sorry.